# Looking for most performant way to execute several similar WP queries within shortcodes

Tags: php, wp-query, mysql, advanced-custom-fields, performance

I have a very data-driven website where each page contains several (5-10) shortcodes, each of which execute WP queries and display the results.

The queries are usually quite similar - I've added 3 examples of a var_dump of the WP query $args to this codeshare: https://codeshare.io/3AvRgv

I'm looking for a way to improve performance, and wonder if there's a better way of doing this than having a new WP_query every time.

For example could I set some query parameters in a custom field, run the query when the page loads, save the array of post_ids to a variable, and then modify them to suit? Would that help?

Any ideas welcome!

Comment: Maybe use the Query Monitor plugin to figure out whether your performance problems are DBMS-based?  And, if you can, try to add a persistent object cache to your tech stack.

Answer (score 2):

I think, it would be hard to achieve this, on the PHP-side as there is not much to gain in how you execute the WP_Query, because it will still result in the same WP_Queries executing the same logic under the hood.

There is however "easy" performance to gain by either; not using WP_Query and for instance writing a more specific SQL query by using (e.g.) $wpdb (which in my experience still doesn't do a whole lot, depending of course on how many meta_queries are adding JOINS and using extra tables etc.), but the biggest gain would be to execute the query's themselves less, by e.g. caching their results.

But this is only a good idea depending on how quickly your data changes.

Since days of php7 versions and especially now with php8, the execution of php itself wouldn't be the bottleneck as much as in the past.
Although, WordPress in itself is not built on "modern" ideas or php, the biggest performance is lost in it's simple, but not very performance-friendly database structure.

Finally if you can't cache your data, or use $wpdb, the key would be in making your queries as simple as the wanted response allows them to be, and try to avoid meta_queries as much as possible.

Oh, and also, avoid ordering your posts by random.

I will add a little snippet below, I once wrote to explain why not, to some colleagues, it could be useful:

Further, if you really can only try and speed up the php code itself, try to use as many [type-hinting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php), and strict type comparisons (=== instead of ==) as you can in your functions, this is often overlooked, because it is generally not promoted in the WordPress docs (because they want to be backwards-compatible as far as possible), but this makes the compiler have to do less work.

Another thing you could try is be as direct as possible. What I mean by this, is WordPress gives you a lot of wrapper functions which just wrap around other code, which might be harder to understand, or performing extra checks. If you look at the [get_posts() function](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.9/src/wp-includes/post.php#L2393) it checks a lot of conditions, which eventually lead to the creation of a new `WP_Query` instance, where if you would create that yourself you could skip a bunch of checks (If you are using wp functions, try to take a look at what they do, and if you can replicate that in a simpler manner).

But once again, I don't think the performance gains, in writing faster code would be consistent and substantial enough.

If you want to make a function to "generate" your similar WP_Queries faster, do consider that your code for creating the WP_Query is probably for php 10% of the work opposed to the 90% of work that is triggered by the WP_Query class itself, so I think the key would be in caching and re-using retrieved data where you can and also to keep your queries as simple as possible.

The snippet (do note that these results where not really consistent or substantial):

```
   /**
     * Get a random post ID from wpdb or, when passed, a random ID of a post which meets the requirements.
     *
     */
    function sb_get_random_post_id(string $post_type = null, string $post_status = 'publish'): int
    {
        global $wpdb;
    
        $query           = "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_status = '%s' ";
        $query_arguments = [$post_status];
    
        if ($post_type) {
            $query             .= "AND post_type = '%s' ";
            $query_arguments[] = $post_type;
        }
    
        $prepared_statement = $wpdb->prepare($query, ...$query_arguments);
        $postID             = $wpdb->get_var($prepared_statement);
    
        return (int) $postID;
    }
    
    /**
     * Get a random post or, a random post within the defined parameters.
     */
    function sb_get_random_post(string $post_type = null, string $post_status = 'publish'): ?\WP_Post
    {
        $random_id = sb_get_random_post_id($post_type, $post_status);
    
        return \get_post($random_id);
    }
    
    /**
     * Random post
     */
    $random_post = sb_get_random_post();
    
    /**
     * Random Woocommerce Order, shop_order uses defferent statusses so one with status 'publish' wouldn't exist.
     */
    $random_completed_wc_order = sb_get_random_post('shop_order', 'wc-completed');
    
    /**
     * Why would you go this length?
     * Here's a function using WP_Query
     * 
     * When timing sb_get_random_post() vs get_random_query_post() the results are:
     * sb_get_random_post:    0.004508972167968
     * get_random_query_post: 0.011613130569458
     
     * random_query_post executes one db query and takes almost three times as long as our function which executes two
     * queries because it first queries our ID and effectively has to run a second query when get_post($random_id) is called.
     * Just imagine that a wordpress page load does up till 100+ queries on average, which will cause every page load to
     * take seconds.
     */
    function get_random_query_post(string $post_type = null, string $post_status = 'publish')
    {
        $args = [
            'post_status'    => $post_status,
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'order'          => 'rand',
            'orderby'        => 'ID',
        ];
    
        $query = new \WP_Query($args);
        return $query->get_posts();
    }
```